# Track signup conversion in Google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I have set up a goal in Google analytics to fire when a user signs up and I am interested to know what is the conversion rate of completion broken down by traffic channel.

The problem is that Google analytics takes into account all visitors to calculate the conversion rate, regardless of whether they are users or not (have or have not completed the goal previously).

Is there any way to track the conversion rate only for users/visitors that are new and not take into account visits that have from users that have already signed up?

Answer (score 0):

Google will only count one goal conversion per session...but if they come back during another session and fill out the form again...then Google is going to count it again. You could segment your goal funnel based on new vs returning users...but that's still not exactly what you're asking either.

Depending on how your form is setup and your goal, you could do this, but only if you're also keeping track of the users based on if they're "logged into" your site or something. For example:

1) You'd need a "destination url" goal setup that would count when the person completes filling out the form based on a virtual pageview (and not the actual url of the "thank you" or whatever...if it's already an ajax form...then you'd be using a virtual pageview anyway)...at that point, you would set a 1st party cookie to track that they filled out the form, and send a virtual pageview to GA to trigger the goal.

2) If they return and have your 1st party cookie set (meaning they filled out the form), and filled out the form again, you simply wouldn't send the virtual pageview.

However, this all depends on them retaining their cookies in their browser.